# Create a dict of column: sql datatypes from a SQLAlchemy Model?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Say I create a model using SQLAlchemy.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
```

How do i create a dict of column:sql datatypes?

For example:

```
_dict = {
    'id': Integer,
    'name': String,
    'fullname': String,
    'password': String
}
```

Ultimitely,  I would like to pass this dict to pandas to_sql function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just build your dictionary from the columns of the table underlying your mapped class:

```
_dict = {c.name: c.type for c in User.__table__.c}
```